# Bash - Count how often a line appears

Tags: linux, bash

File A is the file I have to search through. File B is the File, that has what I need to search in file A.

File A is a lot of code, simular to this:

```
test test 
a = rr
b = gg
test test
c = a + b
test
```

Those variables are sometimes only declared, and not used, and I filtered all variables, that I need out, into File B:

```
a
b
```

I want to count how often each variable (each variable in File B has its own line, and is a string), appears in File B.

I would use `count if` in `Excel` to get this going, but I don´t know how to do something simular in Bash.

I tried to use
`grep -wc File_B File_A`
But this did not work for me, I guess its because this try´s to find the complete File_B in File_A, but that does not work.

Any help would be apprechiated.

Kind regards

Elias

Comment: Do you want a separate count per string to search for or do you want a total count? And what you search for is it literal strings or regular expressions? Please edit your question to specify this (do not give this information in comments). If you want separate counts `grep` is not the right tool; try `awk`.  If you want a total count try `grep -f File_B -wc Fila_A`. If what you search for is literal strings (not regular expressions) add the `-F` option: `grep -f File_B -Fwc Fila_A`.

Comment: Please clearly explain if you want a separate count or a global one. And please also show your expected output for your example.

Comment: @Elias: So, you don't have any comment lines in File_A?

Comment: Yes, but I removed those previous, would comments be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

The command `grep -wc File_B File_A` actually searches for the *word* `File_B` in the file `File_A`.

What you may have wanted is `grep -wcf File_B File_A` - the `-f` means "don't search for the pattern `File_B`, instead read the patterns to search from `File_B`.

The thing is, that will count all the matches from `File_B` that are found in `File_A` and sum it for you, so if the pattern on the first line of `File_B` is found 8 times, and the pattern on the second line of `File_B` is found 4 times, `grep -wcf` will just print 12. If you want to have an output that lists how many times each pattern was found, you'd want to write a loop that reads each line from `File_B` and `grep`s for it individually.

Maybe something like this:

```bash
while read pat; do echo -n "$pat: "; grep -wc "$pat" File_A; done < File_B
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfektly, I think I am able to work with that. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the option `-F` would also make sense. At least it would speed up things a bit.

Comment: I now have a bit of a different problem, when I run the code you added in the edit, the output is `variable: 1`. I would like to sort this in descending order. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I now used `awk` to change both columns, and was able to sort it in descending order.